# How to load DATETIME object from YAML file?

Tags: java, playframework-2.0, yaml, jodatime, playframework-2.1

I'm using JODA TIME library for persisting DATETIMEs. Before I run my tests I need to setup test data. So I've a yaml file where I've defined test data with dates which I was hoping would convert into DATETIME objects but they are not.

I'm using Play Framework 2.0. Any idea how I can convert YAML date into a real DATETIME object.

Here's how my yaml file look like

```
users:
    - !!models.User
        createdOn:     2001-09-09T01:46:40Z
        fName:         Mike
        lName:         Roller
```

Answer (score 1):

Taken from [snakeyaml project WIKI](https://bitbucket.org/asomov/snakeyaml/wiki/Howto#markdown-header-how-to-parse-jodatime). Examples are [here](https://bitbucket.org/asomov/snakeyaml/src/tip/src/test/java/examples/jodatime/).

## How to parse JodaTime

Since JodaTime is no JavaBean (because it does not have an empty constructor), it requires some extra treatment when parsing:

```
private class ConstructJodaTimestamp extends ConstructYamlTimestamp {
    public Object construct(Node node) {
        Date date = (Date) super.construct(node);
        return new DateTime(date, DateTimeZone.UTC);
    }
}
```

When the JodaTime instance is the JavaBean property you can use the following:

```
Yaml y = new Yaml(new JodaPropertyConstructor());

class JodaPropertyConstructor extends Constructor {
    public JodaPropertyConstructor() {
        yamlClassConstructors.put(NodeId.scalar, new TimeStampConstruct());
    }

    class TimeStampConstruct extends Constructor.ConstructScalar {
        @Override
        public Object construct(Node nnode) {
            if (nnode.getTag().equals("tag:yaml.org,2002:timestamp")) {
                Construct dateConstructor = yamlConstructors.get(Tag.TIMESTAMP);
                Date date = (Date) dateConstructor.construct(nnode);
                return new DateTime(date, DateTimeZone.UTC);
            } else {
                return super.construct(nnode);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
org.joda.time.DateTime getDateFromFile(final String string, final String path) throws IOException {
   final BufferedReader f = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
   String s;
   final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".+" + string + ".+([0-9\\-:ZT]+)");
   while ((s = f.readLine()) != null)
    {
       final Matcher m = pattern.matcher(s);
       if (m.matches())
       {
           return ISODateTimeFormatter.dateTimeNoMillis().parseDateTime(m.group(1));
       }
    }


    return null;
}
```

use method

```
getDateFromFile("createdOn:", pathToFile)
```